# Error in loading mnist dataset in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, decode, pickle, mnist

When trying to load the MNIST dataset with a mnist_loader script, I keep on getting  the following error: 
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 614: ordinal not in range(128)'

The code used to load the data is shown below. Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

```
def load_data():
    f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work with Python 3, the code is given below:

```
import pickle
import gzip
with gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle._Unpickler(f)
    data.encoding = 'latin1'  # set encoding
    train, valid, test = data.load()
```

Comment: can confirm that it works with python 3.8.12